# Color underline on C# colors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've recently reinstalled Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 + Resharper. After the reinstall some color-underlining have stopped working.
It used to create a blue line below `Colors.Blue` and a green line below `Colors.Green`. The IntelliSense also had colored squares when listing colors.

Here's an example of code where the coloring is missing:

```
textBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

How do I get the underline colors and IntelliSense colors to work again?

Comment: did you used to have [devColor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7dbae8b3-5812-490e-913e-7bfe17f47f1d/?SRC=VSIDE) installed?  Although it looks like that's more to do with web colors - however, it's got to be some missing extension or a differently configured extension

Comment: The DevExpress products have that feature, though I doubt you were using those in conjunction with Resharper...

Comment: No I didn't used to have devColor installed. I don't think I installed any extensions for it. To me it seemed like a standard feature in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ReSharper documentation for this feature is here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Color_Assistance.html

As it says there, the setting is controlled within:

> To highlight color usages
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose ReSharper | Options.
> 2. The Options dialog box opens. Click Settings on the left pane of the dialog.
> 3. Select the Highlight color usages check box on the Settings pane.
> 4. Click Save or Save To to apply changes.

Comment: I had installed an old version of ReSharper, which didn't have this color functionality. Your answer made me realize the setting don't exist in the older version. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you had [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features2010#ColorsHighlighting) installed (note: it works in more places than just css):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7dbae8b3-5812-490e-913e-7bfe17f47f1d/?SRC=VSIDE

I don t know what that feature should have to do with resharper

Comment: @thefiloe This is a ReSharper feature.

Answer (score -3):

```
  textBox.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

use this i think this is work

Comment: You described how to set a foreground color for a textbox for winforms, he uses WPF/silverlight as you can see by the SolidColorBrush, but that is completly not where this question is about. This question is about the IDE